# How to call my onchange function after my blur function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a blur function already attached to my dropdown, now I want to call another function onchange after my blur function is called in javasript.

```
<select onchange="CheckAccommodation(this)" onblur="return UpdateFormSelect('UpdatePrice.aspx', 'BookNow_accommodation1', 'select', 'BookNow_accommduration');javascript:test()" id="BookNow_accommodation1" name="BookNow:accommodation1">
```

Now I want to call my **javascript:test()** after the blur is done

Please suggest!

Thanks.

Best Regards,
Yuv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now I want to call my javascript:test() after the blur is done

Then just remove the ‘return’ on the first statement, allowing it to fall through to the second:

```
onblur="UpdateFormSelect('UpdatePrice.aspx', 'BookNow\_accommodation1', 'select', 'BookNow\_accommduration');test()"
```

You could put `return test()`, but actually onblur doesn't need to return anything. `<a onclick>` often needs to `return false` to stop the link being followed, but other than that you often don't need any return value from an event handler.

It's also a bit of a mouthful to put in an event handler. You might benefit by breaking the JavaScript out:

```
<select id="BookNow_accommodation1" name="BookNow:accommodation1">
    ...
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var acc1= document.getElementById('BookNow_accommodation1');
    acc1.onchange= function() {
        CheckAccommodation(this);
        // or just move the body of CheckAccommodation here
    };
    acc1.onblur= function() {
        UpdateFormSelect('UpdatePrice.aspx', 'BookNow_accommodation1', 'select', 'BookNow_accommduration');
        test();
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This suggested by @Ghommey will work:

```
<select onchange="CheckAccommodation(this)" onblur="return 
    UpdateFormSelect('UpdatePrice.aspx', 'BookNow_accommodation1', 
     'select', 'BookNow_accommduration');test()" id="BookNow_accommodation1" 
     name="BookNow:accommodation1">
```

it works irrespective of what you return from `UpdateFormSelect`.

```
function onChangeHandler(){
    //.........
}

$("SELECT_ID").blur(function(){
    //handle blur

    //call on change handler
    onChangeHandler();
});
```

Comment: Many Thanks, please have a look to my code added in question.